# Search site by two possible abbreviation combinations - with space and without

Tags: seo, wordpress, meta-tags, search, yoast

I have a case where company name is registered as abbrevation, lets call it KUBER. But first two letters represent names of two founders so the client wishes that website will be found on search engines if the user types in "KU BER" or "KUBER". Official registered company name is without space just "KUBER" but the domain name is "ku-ber.com" to further add to the confusion.

Search engines discontinued use of meta keywords: [Article](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/meta-keywords-yoast-seo/) and new recommended way is to use focus keyword. My question is, how to tell search engines both words should find the company?

I can't use meta keywords because Wordpress plugin YOAST doesn't have the option anymore. Only options are title, focus keyword and meta description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, search engines (particularly Google) do a good job of resolving this issue for you. If I search for `kuber` or `ku ber` I get *similar* results. Searching for `ku ber` (with a space) also returns many results containing just `kuber` (no space).

> Search engines discontinued use of meta keywords

Yes, the *keywords* meta tag plays no part whatsoever in mainstream search.

> Only options are title, focus keyword and meta description.

Whilst the *description* meta tag can appear in the SERPS, its not actually used for search itself. So using keywords in this tag will not help you.

As far as I know, the "focus keyword" that YOAST reports is just a tool to help you target your content - it doesn't actually play a part in search itself.

The `<title>` is certainly useful to target keywords. As is the *content* of your pages. If you want to explicitly target both "kuber" and "ku ber" then both should appear in your content somewhere. However, you need to also be consistent - otherwise you just confuse your users. So, you can't just switch between "kuber" and "ku ber" in the same context as that just looks like a typo.

You need to focus on one version (I suspect "kuber" since that is the registered company name) and perhaps explain elsewhere (eg. on the "about" page) how the name came about with some background. There you can include "ku ber", etc.

> but the domain name is "ku-ber.com" to further add to the confusion.

Yes, that does add to the confusion! The domain name itself does not help so much in search.